# How to programmatically create a shortcut of another app in Android?

Tags: android

Suppose, I have some Android app which helps users to install some other apps. Is there any way to create a shortcut of this apps on home screen? Can I also specify the position of these shortcuts?

Comment: I don't understand; What do you mean shortcuts? So you want to create app icons/widgets for the installed apps?

Comment: @LotusUNSW Yes, I want to create app icons for the installed apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
public void createShortCut() {
    Intent shortcutintent = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    shortcutintent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
    shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getString(R.string.shortcutname));
    Parcelable icon = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext, R.drawable.icon);
    shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, icon);
    shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, new Intent("com.whatsapp"));
    sendBroadcast(shortcutintent);
}
```

Comment: thanx for the code but is there a way to check if a similar short cut already exists before creating a newer one ?

Comment: Try with shortcutintent.putExtra("duplicate", false);

Comment: You missed () after methodName (I have added)

Answer (score -1):

A bit improved version: we are checking if the shortcut has been already created 
and must not be created if user remove it from the screen

```
final static private String PREF_KEY_SHORTCUT_ADDED = "PREF_KEY_SHORTCUT_ADDED";

    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();

// Checking if ShortCut was already added
        sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean shortCutWasAlreadyAdded = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_KEY_SHORTCUT_ADDED, false);
        if (!shortCutWasAlreadyAdded) createShortcutIcon();


    } // end onStart


    // Creates shortcut on Android widget screen
    private void createShortcutIcon(){

        Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Splash.class);
        shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        Intent addIntent = new Intent();
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getString(R.string.app_name));

        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.ic_launcher));

        addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);

        // Remembering that Shortcut was already added
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(PREF_KEY_SHORTCUT_ADDED, true);
        editor.commit();

        objPublicDelegate.showToast(getString(R.string.app_name)+ " shortcut created on screen.");

    } // end createShortcutIcon
```

Comment: Thanks. shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); Without these two lines, sometimes app is crashing saying "TransactionTooLargeException". To avoid this exception, its mandatory to add these lines.

Answer (score -2):

There is no such API on Android.

Comment: i thing you should comment rather than answer.